# What's the point of the bombable caves with golden statues?

Tags: zelda-links-awakening

> [image]

This has to be the third or fourth such room in the game. This particular room is deep within an area that can only be reached with the rooster. I imagine that if I can do something here, I probably can only do so here and now.

What's the point of these rooms? How do I activate them? What do I get from it?

Comment: If it matters, I'm yet to play through level seven.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a Fairy Spring. If you have taken damage, there should be a nice fairy there who will heal all of your hearts of damage. When you aren't harmed, however, it will just be empty.

[image]

'Tis why the statues are of fairies.

Comment: Oh... (almost) whenever I took damage I rolled back the game two seconds and tried again. No wonder nothing ever happened here...